# Does the "powermetrics" command line tool come pre installed on mac?

Tags: macos, terminal

I wanted to know if "powermetrics" command comes pre installed on macOS or is it something that needs to be installed?

Comment: What will happen if you enter it in terminal? With high probability 'powermetrics must be invoked as the superuser'

Comment: yup it must be invoked with superuser

Comment: `type powermetrics`. If it's in one of the standard directories it's part of macOS (unless you disabled SIP to install it but then you wouldn't ask :-)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is present on macOS, (my MBA is running Catalina,) but you need to run it as root using `sudo`:

```
Last login: Wed Nov  4 07:52:42 on console
[tech-computer:~] admin% powermetrics
powermetrics must be invoked as the superuser
[tech-computer:~] admin% sudo powermetrics
Password:
Machine model: MacBookAir8,1
SMC version: Unknown
EFI version: 1037.4.0
OS version: 19H2
Boot arguments: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev
Boot time: Wed Nov  4 07:52:07 2020
.
.
.
```

Comment: I have a Mac running 10.11 (Catalina is 10.15) and it appears there as well. It can be found at `/usr/bin/powermetrics`